# Auto load text to textbox from file location

Tags: c#

So I am trying to load text from a file location so I need to start off with creating a file location and then using that file location to load the text to my text boxes.

So I want to create the file location...
@"C:\Program Files (x86)\CPA\Text[number].txt"

Then in that location I would like to have my [number] text files

```
one.txt
two.txt
three.txt
four.txt
five.txt
six.txt
seven.txt
eight.txt
```

Then I need the tool to automatically load the text files to the text boxes

For my buttons to save the text I am using...

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "one|*.txt"; //Should I name it 'one.txt' instead ?
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;
        File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, this.textBox1.Text);
```

I plan on using the following to get the location...

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\CPA\Text"))
            {
                //Load text to textboxes

            }
```

But I am not sure how to load text to the text boxes automatically without asking the user to select the text files using open file dialogue

Comment: Look into `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(string path)`

Answer (score 0):

You can load the contents of a text file into a string variable using the `File.ReadAllText` method. You just pass this method the path to a file, and it will open the file, read the contents, return them as a string, and close the file.

You might consider keeping your files in a directory along with your executable. This way it's easy to find and always stays near your exe.

To get the directory that your executable lives in, you can do this:

```
// This requires "using System.Reflection" at the top of your .cs file
var thisExeDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Then you might want to have a folder underneath that directory to store your files, like a "FileData" directory:

```
var myFileDirectory = Path.Combine(thisExeDirectory, "FileData");
```

If you don't want to do this, you can just do what you are already doing:

```
var myFileDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\CPA\Text[number].txt";
```

In any case, here's an example of how you can read the contents of a file into a textbox:

```
// Get the full path to the file
var filePath = Path.Combine(myFileDirectory, "one.txt");

// If it exists, write the contents to a textbox
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
}
```

Now later, if you want to overwrite the file with the contents of the text box, you can use a similar method called `File.WriteAllText`:

```
// If the directory does not exist, create it
Directory.CreateDirectory(myFileDirectory);

File.WriteAllText(filePath, textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: So this is how it should look in my form1 initialization
https://gyazo.com/332a044d6a5882840590346c86065f0a

Comment: And my save button should look like this https://gyazo.com/defb4a0976bd61598576142b1ef71647

Comment: I end up getting this error though "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Comment: On this line 
File.WriteAllText(filePath, textBox1.Text);

Comment: Okay so it works with my save feature but not with the auto load text to text boxes here is the code I currently have set for that https://gyazo.com/9ab1b223167b1dd7d4936663fc9ed510

Comment: how is it not working? Is there an exception? If so,  on which line?

Comment: if you could message me and help me out, I can't start a conversation on here yet

Comment: Until you can describe ***how*** it's not working, I cannot help you. If there are no exceptions being thrown then most likely the call to `if (File.Exists(filePath))` is returning `false` because the file isn't there, so no text is written in your textbox. Also, in your screenshot you are checking the same `filePath` in both your `if` conditions. Don't you want to check for `filePath2` (and use `filePath2` for the `textBox2.Text` assignment) in the second one?